# Linq query error pulling blob image from database...object must implement IConvertible

Tags: c#, subsonic

My query returns an error saying "Object must implement IConvertible".  The error occurs on the .FirstOrDefault() line.  I am trying to pull a blob image from a database and return it to the ajax call.  I have been searching for 2 days for an answer and can't find anything.

```
        [HttpGet]
        //[Authorize]
        public ActionResult getChartInfo(string ticker)
        {
            var db = new MarketSymmetricsSite.msxxdbDB();

            System.Linq.IQueryable<string> gQuery = (System.Linq.IQueryable<string>)(from mg in db.Markets where mg.tickerID == ticker select mg.pGraph);
            string mGraph = gQuery.FirstOrDefault(); ;
            byte[] test = new byte[mGraph.Length];
            char[] CharArray = mGraph.ToCharArray();

            byte[] ByteArray = new byte[CharArray.Length];

            for (int i = 0; i < CharArray.Length; i++)
            {

                ByteArray[i] = Convert.ToByte(CharArray);

            }

            return Json(ByteArray, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
```

Comment: have you looked this resource:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266223/retrieving-an-image-from-database-with-linq-to-sql

Comment: I did see that one and it did not work for me.

Comment: @user1361962 try the updated example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this all I had to do was change the data type in the database from blob to binary and voila.  Hope this will help anyone who may need it.

Comment: Congrats on the fix!  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' (with the green checkmark) so that others will be able to learn from your success.  Cheers~

Answer (score 0):

you need to use var and then convert image from binary so it an image file now

```
var img = (from mg in db.Markets where mg.tickerID == ticker select mg.pGraph).FirstOrDefault();
va rconvertedimage = ByteArrayToImage(img.Image.ToArray());
```

Comment: @user1361962 are sure it an image binary not a string

Comment: should be..it is originally a jpg image stored in a MySQL database as a blob type

Comment: The problem is that the error is occurring on the query...i never get to the code after the query

Comment: "Object must implement IConvertible"